# Not Getting Claims after refreshing token Silently

Tags: ios, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm signin to B2C after that i call my api to create vendor and after that i call aquireTokenSilent to get the add claims in jwt Token.But unfortunately i'm not getting added claims in Access token.I checked user identity also it is also same as in sign.
Any help what i'm missing?
How to get the added claims by refreshing token?

Answer (score 0):

There's a delay.  I've seen it take a few mins.

Comment: Do you know any solution? or i need to call refresh token untill i get my claims.Is that will be correct approach?

Comment: exactly, call refresh until the claims you expect are there.